# As of 2023 June, what is the best method to swap USDC from Arbitrum to Polygon with the least slippage

Tags: arbitrum, usdc, bridge, polygon-bridge

It's June 2023, what is the most cost effective way to swap USDC from Arbitrum to Polygon?